# Boxes and Labels Not Aligned CSS

Tags: asp.net, html, css

Based on this answer [StackOverflow @Nikita Rybak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3732313/461887) I have created a set of labels and textboxes following his solution which shows to be working on JSFiddle.

I have copied this and added a few more categories to my ASP project but when loaded into chrome the boxes and text are all out of align.

This is my html file

```
<div id="User">
<div>
<div class="left">
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_UserName" runat="server" Text="User Name"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtbx_UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="left">
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_FirstName" runat="server" Text="First Name"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtbx_FirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="left">
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_Password" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtbx_Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</div>

<div>
<div class="left">
    <asp:Label ID="lbl_ConfPassword" runat="server" Text="Confirm Password"></asp:Label>
</div>
<div class="right">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtbx_ConfPassword" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and my CSS file

```
#Content
{
    position: relative;
    float:none;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    float: left;
    padding: 80px 40px 60px 40px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    left: 0px; right: 0px;
    text-align: center;   
}

#User .left {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;}

#User .right {
    width: 65%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float:left;}
```

Is there a reason why mine does not work?

Comment: As an aside, be nice to your users and add the [`AssociatedControlID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.associatedcontrolid.aspx) attribute to your labels: `<asp:Label AssociatedControlID="txtbx_UserName" ID="lbl_UserName" runat="server" Text="User Name"></asp:Label>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work okay, though you have a few too many divs in there unnecessarily, and you also have a line break that may be screwing things up. Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jesus_tesh/JnUWx/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="User">
    <div class="left">
        <label>User name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <label>First name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <label>Password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="left">
        <label>Confirm password</label>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
#User .left {
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;}

#User .right {
    width: 65%;
    margin-left: 10px;
    float:left;}​
```

Also, you have a #Content element defined in your CSS nut it is not in the HTML, so that *could* be causing the problem.

**EDIT**
The only other thing I can think of is that the label control wraps the text in a  - maybe try a literal control? The fiddle works fine, so it must be something with webforms controls.

Comment: The #content  is part of the main.css for the master page . I was hoping creating the #user class would resolve any other style sheet inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Float sHould be used very carefully. Instead yo can use position attribute to position your div's accordingly.

Comment: -1 for this suggestion. Positioning is less flexible than floats. If you know what you are doing, you should definitely use floats over positioning if you want an easy to maintain structure. I rarely use positioning unless I need something in a very precise spot.