# Have Text & Label Appear On Same Line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am stumped on this, as I have tried both CSS, and straight HTML by way of a table to have my text and text box appear on the same line, however either method always puts the text on top of the text box.  I like the table method since my CSS method just splits the page in half and there is awkward space between the text boxes.

However, question being - what is the way in HTML (and we can use JavaScript, JQuery, CSS, HTML etc) to format this accordingly?

**Attempt 1**

```
<table>
 <tr>
    <td>Payroll End Date:<input type="date" name="enddate" value="<?= $_POST['psdate'] ?>"></td>
    <td>Payroll End Date:<input type="date" name="startdate" value="<?= $_POST['pedate'] ?>"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

**Attempt 2**

```
<div id="right">Payroll End Date:<input type="date" name="enddate" value="<?= $_POST['psdate'] ?>"></div>
<div id="left">Payroll End Date:<input type="date" name="startdate" value="<?= $_POST['pedate'] ?>"></div>


#left {
  float: right ;
  width: 50% ;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: You have to make the `input` a `display: inline-block;` in css

Comment: Your table and div seem fine... What problem are you having with your body setup? Also remember tables are not really good for responsiveness.

Comment: @Samuel - for example, see this fiddle - the text appears above the date picker.  I want the text to appear to the left of it  http://fiddlesalad.com/html/

Comment: Lots of ways to do it. We don't really know what your expectations are

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3732313/1527252) will help you

Comment: @Samuel - that puts text and textbox on one line but does not keep it all on one line http://jsfiddle.net/qP46X/

Comment: @charlietfl - my desired output is to have on ONE line text datepicker then a tab text datepicker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example - it works for me and puts everything on one line

```
<div name="payroll" id="oneline">
Payroll End Date:<input type="date" name="enddate" value="<?= $_POST['psdate'] ?>">
Payroll End Date:<input type="date" name="startdate" value="<?= $_POST['pedate'] ?>">
</div>
```

and add some css flavor

```
#oneline {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: right;
}
```

And a handy fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/Lera/HEeHd/